# python re.search() find none

Tags: python, regex

```
s="XX.1.1. Accidents"
pattern = re.compile(r'\d|[a-zA-Z]\.\s([a-zA-Z]\S+)')
match=pattern.search(s)
if match:
   print(match.group(1))
```

the output is None. However, I think it should have been "Accidents" Can someone tell me why?

Comment: This just matches a digit which is the first pattern in the alternation. Use `match.group()` to see it. If you want `Accidents`, why are you searching for `\d`? I don't see anything with an alphanumeric followed by literal period followed by space followed by alpha followed by nonspace+. Did you mean somethig like `\d\. ([a-zA-Z]\S+)`?

Answer (score 3):

Your `|` is messing with it - since you're not placing it in a capturing group or anything, it'll match `\d` or **all** of `[a-zA-Z]\.\s([a-zA-Z]\S+)`. This is an issue because the regex will act greedily and you'll end up just a single `\d`.

If you use `(?:\d|[a-zA-Z])\.\s([a-zA-Z]\S+)`, it'll work properly and you'll receive `Accidents`.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the whole first part in square brackets, then search for the space, and then for the characters and the rest:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z\d.]*\s([a-zA-Z]\S+)')
```